# Designing PID to reject load disturbances of dead-time process

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, matlab, simulink

I am using the PID Tuner for the PID Controller Block in Simulink. I am particularly interested in the output disturbance BODE plot. I am trying to achieve an acceptable output disturbance with the follow requirements:

1. Attenuation of at least 10 dB with frequencies less than 0.5 Hz
2. Flat response (0 dB) at higher frequencies with no overshoot.

---

By raising the bandwidth of the controller, see image below.

[image: raising the bandwidth of the controller]

I am able to achieve the appropriate attenuation at < 0.5 Hz, but I am getting a nasty overshoot at 4 Hz, which is unacceptable. Lowering the bandwidth, see image below, removes the overshoot but then I have poor attenuation.

[image: Lowering the bandwidth]

---

My plant is:

\$G(s) = \frac{4.1s + 59.5}{s^2 + 34.1s + 385.7}×e^{-0.05s}\$

Other than adjusting bandwidth and phase margin, is there anything else I can try to achieve both of these requirements?

If it isn't evident. I am not an expert in controls engineering. I apologise in advanced if this question seems novice.

Thank you,

Comment: I like the linking to gyazo, it shows that you're rebellious.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Did I break any forum rules? I am unaware.

Comment: My point is flying too high, what I'm saying is that it's unnecessary to be _sloppy_. If a question asks for people to click links and decipher what your question _really_ is about, 99% of them will give up. If you however present it like x-3 = 0 where you see the question and the problem instantly, then you'll receive proper answers.  And the thing with gyazo is that there's already a built in image uploader here at stackexchange because a question should be able to stand on its own. I'm not trying to be mean, just giving some advice, don't take it the wrong way. It's a good question.

Comment: Google 'Smith Predictor Controller'

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thanks Harry, I will keep in mind the etiquette.

Comment: @Chu, I have already implemented a SP and output disturbance rejection improved with a negligible amount. Are there any other architectures I can take a look at that is suitable for this problem?